# Problems running ppl_detection in astar-ros-pkg

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to use the ppl_detection in the astar-ros-pkg:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ppl_detection

As soon as I run the node, it exits and throws me a segmentation fault.

the error displayed is given below:

[rviz-7] process has died [pid 4034, exit code -11].

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10345/problems-running-ppl_detection-in-astar-ros-pkg/) by [Deepak](https://answers.ros.org/users/607/deepak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No activity > 1 month, closing

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try changing line 468 of kinect_detect.cpp from:
std::string model_string = "svm_models/" + model_name + ".model";
to:
std::string model_string = "../svm_models/" + model_name + ".model";

This fixed the segfaulting for me.

---

Originally posted by [Liz Murphy](https://answers.ros.org/users/425/liz-murphy/) with karma: 83 on 2011-11-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2012-01-18**:
worked for me changing that line to std::string model_string = "./svm_models/" + model_name + ".model"; as suggested by @IsaacSaito

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you believe the segmentation fault occurs at `RViz`, [this thread](http://answers.ros.org/question/2791/ppl_detection-package?answer=4979#4979) might be of help.

Else if you experience seg-fault while trying to run `kinect_detect`, first of all the current implementation requires you run the command from the home directory of `ppl_detection` (by `roscd ppl_detection` or something. See around line#468 in `kinect_detect.cpp` where relative path of `.model` file is specified). Then try what @Liz Murphy suggests. If that still doesn't solve, modify the same part as:

```
std::string model_string = "./svm_models/" + model_name + ".model";
```

On one of my notebook (`Ubuntu 11.04, Intel i7, ROS electric`), I didn't have to do anything for `kinect_detect`, but on `Turtlebot (eeepc)`, I had to do the above (maybe it's rooted in that the way `fopen` in `C++` treats the current directory varies depending on the computer architecture? I haven't investigated further).

HTH.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2011-12-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2012-01-18**:
worked for me, changing the kinect_detect.cpp.  thanks!